# Using jquery/js in app to strip css search results page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm attempting to build an app that hits my website's search and pulls up the results in the app.

Currently I just have an `iframe` in the app that basically pulls up my entire websites search results, the header, banner, css, etc., so having an entire website in an iframe in an app doesn't look pretty.

My question is, how would I use jquery/javascript in my website's search results page so that it looks to see if the search that just happened came from my app or my website?

And then if it came from my app, change the css to strip off all the decorations, footer, banner, etc. so that it would just display results.

Should I do something like a get parameter on the URL to differentiate?

I'm extremely new to jquery/javascript, my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is not needed, you can use [CSS Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) to hide that extra content based on the screen size. You can use something like this in your stylesheet:

```
@media (max-width:500px) {
    #banner, #footer, .decorations {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

This will make it so that when the display window is less than 500 pixels wide the elements with the id's banner and footer, and any elements with the class decorations will be hidden.